# Making column layout which flows in order

Tags: html, css

I have three columns on my site and I like the way it looks, although the code isn't in order (they are like blog posts so I would expect the first to be the most recent then in order the the last post.

But because of the structure I have to put them in order across the columns separately which is a little fiddly and I am sure there's a better solution.  I am not a big fan of Javascript and if it's possible using CSS on its own I would be so thankful..

http://www.poipleshadow.com/Children-Charity-Pictures.htm

its all ok, although I would prefer it if the items in the columns were in date order, at the moment they are in date order but per column.

So in conclusion i want them to be displayed in the source like

A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I

but displayed

```
A  B  C
D  E  F
G  H  I
```

Comment: But there isn't room on the page to list them side by side. I don't get what you mean. They are doing what you want them to do within the constraints of the page width from what I can see.

Comment: p.s Very worthy cause, good job.

Comment: Hi webnoob, thanks - My way is working although in the source code they are out of order  In the source code they are in the order of ADG BEH and CFI, which is fine, although not nice. Makes it a little harder to update new stories, but nothing serious just a bit annoying...  Sebastian Graz below has given great solutions, just have to worry about IE9 and below...  Thanks for liking the cause :) 

It's all new so currently trying to think of a name, so let me know if you have any good ideas for names for children's charitys (based in India) - needs to be fun and original :)  THanks

Comment: This question seems to be asked a bit, I should have looked around first - Thanks everyone for their input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small note, this is only possible in firefox and chrome. Pure masonry layout in CSS is simply not possible. For internet explorer fall back look into packery: http://packery.metafizzy.co/

Edit: If all your boxes have the same height: then add float:left to each of the boxes

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/tQANc/
DEMO V2: http://jsfiddle.net/umbriel/TzkZ8/ 
DEMO V3 IE compatible: http://jsfiddle.net/umbriel/6e6Qy/
HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="cols">
    <div class="box one"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
    <div class="box one"></div>
    <div class="box three"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
    <div class="box five"></div>
    <div class="box one"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
    <div class="box six"></div>
    <div class="box three"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
.cols {
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}
.box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.box.one {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #d77575;
}
.box.two {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #dcbc4c;
}
.box.three {
    background-color: #a3ca3b;
    height: 400px;
}
.box.four {
    background-color: #3daee3;
    height: 500px;
}
.box.five {
    background-color: #bb8ed8;
    height: 600px;
}
.box.six {
    background-color: #baafb1;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Wow!  I should have thought about columns!! Doh!  I put it down to being too close to the problem :)

Thanks so much for the solution.  The world would be a better place without IE! :)  Do you know how Safari etc handle it?  I will have a play anyway and see what happens.

Comment: Safari and chrome uses the same renderer; webkit. So it should be supported in Safari as well

Comment: Also is there a way for it to not split each div from one column to the next?

Comment: In your solution at the bottom of the first column there is a gold box, that 'spills' over to the second column.  I would preferably like it to continue to the end of the first column, or start at the top of the second column...  - Makes Sense?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't quite understnad why making position relative makes it work...  But I still have a lot to learn!! :)  I tried it in IE9.. (Yuk!) at lest it works in IE10..  I would just like to say a HUGE thanks for your help.  You're a star! - Thanks

Comment: The intended way of preventing child elements from being split between columns is to use `break-inside: avoid` (webkit browsers use the deprecated column-break-inside property) on the child elements.  However, Firefox doesn't support it.

Comment: OK..  How would you suggest I handle elegantly the IE9 and below uses?  Having them just shown as full width doesn't really look great (in my mind it's their fault for having IE) but it would be nice to be kind and pat them on their heads and provide a slightly better look - Any Ideas??  If not, no worries - Thanks again

Comment: A more compatible way of doing this is by having multiple columns: http://jsfiddle.net/umbriel/6e6Qy/ I believe this will work in any browser

Comment: THank you, that's what I started with :) - I just noticed that your solution displays the items down first then accross, which I think is the only way without involving javascript or setting it out how I have already. So I think I will end up leaving it as it is.  But thank you so much for your help with the columns, will definately include it in something in the future! :)  THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You just put all  your `div class="blog-item vevent">` one after another in only one `<div class="col span_1_of_3">`(and remove its `width` from `css`)
give them `Width`,`margin`and `float:left;`

Comment: wouldn't fit properly together as shown though using this method (unless all boxes were same height)

Comment: well you can use script  set your elements in specific order to make more stable in `cross browser` @Sebastian Graz gave nice solution

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use an grid system, like the grid fromt http://purecss.io/grids/ 
Yes it contains also a CSS reset and default styles, but it saves you alot of time. You can

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.2.0/base-min.css">


<div class="pure-g">

    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        A
    </div>

    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        B
    </div>

    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        C
    </div>

    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        D
    </div>

    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        E
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1-3">
        F
    </div>

</div>
```